# How to port 'No proxy' setting from Windows to Linux?

Tags: rhel, python, proxy

I am using corporate Windows 10, and I can access to the Jira system by setting 'No proxy' on the MS Edge.
I tried to use the corporate Linux server to access Jira system automatically using Python [atlassian-python-api 3.13.0](https://pypi.org/project/atlassian-python-api/). However, I cannot run the script with below error:

`Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'`

I doubted the 'No proxy' on Linux has not been set similarly to Windows, so I found way to set 'No proxy' on Linux from [Red Hat Customer Portal](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openshift_container_platform/3.4/html/installation_and_configuration/install-config-http-proxies):

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://<user>:<password>@<ip_addr>:<port>/
HTTPS_PROXY=https://<user>:<password>@<ip_addr>:<port>/
NO_PROXY=master.hostname.example.com,10.1.0.0/16,172.30.0.0/16
```

However, it seems that there is no 'standalone' setting for the like 'No proxy' on Windows for Linux. Is it correct?

P/S: I am using Red Hat Enterprise 64bit as company server.

Comment: By default this should already be the case.  What makes you say that it isn't?

Comment: When I execute: ping goolge.com, I get:
PING goolge.com (172.217.26.36) 56(84) bytes of data.
...
Nothing more than that. The command cannot finish, there is no result for ping command. However, I can access google.com with 'No proxy' setting on MS Edge (I can ping google.com by cmd with meaningful results).

Comment: That suggests a network firewall is blocking outgoing PINGs, not a proxy.  PING, also, is ICMP and doesn't obey web proxy settings.  What other evidence do you have that your internet isn't working properly?  (The DNS resolution indicates your internet is at some level working, but PING alone isn't going to be a solution to test/validate proxy settings)

Comment: `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='aaa.aaa.aaa', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: ... (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f25c6a29fd0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out')`

I used Python REST API to get the Jira info via Linux server 64bit (Redhat); but failed because of connection time out. On the other hands, I can access the Jira server normally via MS Edge. What is difference? Then I think the cause is Linux server cannot access Jira server while Windows can.

Comment: I would have to examine the firewall on each system - typically speaking connection timeout issues tend to be *network* related, and if there's a proxy requirement on your network then your specific system needs to be permitted to communicate out through the firewall on the network without needing the proxy to work.  That's something that has to be done at the network administration level.  Is this a corporate network/environment?

Comment: Yes, this is a network/environment for corporate (not my personal PC).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128899/discussion-between-steven-lee-and-thomas-ward).

Comment: As this is a Red Hat system per your chat with me, I'm migrating this to Unix and Linux where it's on topic - Red Hat is not Ubuntu and not on topic here on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: in "no proxy" code for "a proxy" I am confused.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor reading the linked chat will help - they are using no proxy and can't get to the Internet on their RHEL system, ping is blocked, timeout getting to Internet, but DNS works.  All signs a firewall on the network is at play especially since OP stated in chat too this is on a corporate network.

Comment: @ThomasWard So is "no proxy" a proxy. I am confused.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor 'no proxy' means 'no proxy'.  It doesn't mean that a network firewall is not at play.  OP indicated in their comments under my answer that "There is no proxy server on our network, but the dev server is on a different subnet and IT won't let Linux servers traverse out to the Internet via the firewall".  An understanding of basic corporate level network design and how networks operate is needed here to really understand the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my chat comments to you and my comments, Linux systems out of the box do not have any proxy configuration applied.

What you're running into is network level restrictions preventing communication outbound to the Internet at large.  As indicated in comments and chat, this is a corporate network, and not your personal network.

Your only recourse here other than using a proxy is to coordinate with your IT team at the company to determine if the system should be excluded in the Firewall rules so that you can communicate out to your destinations without restrictions.  If there is a proxy on your network, they may want you to configure your application to communicate through that.

Comment: What's a pity! IT refused more detail explanation & maybe there is no proxy on corporate Linux system. The Windows is on the other hands, as you said, in a kind of 'minor' subnet mask & permitted to access the permitted sites. IT said Linux is banned to access any site though. Seem that the only way for me is to use Windows to run my application then.

Comment: I want to run on Linux because the Linux server is running all the time so I can use `crontab` to make the task run periodically. I heard I can do the same on Windows using Jenkins system other while I must trigger the task to run manually then.

Comment: @StevenLee That puts you in the realm of "How do I do this on Windows" which is a Superuser question.  However, you COULD technically install WSL on a Windows computer and it'll look like requests originate from the Windows computer, then using WSL it'll run crontabs, etc. that way.  However bypassing the workplace restrictions won't help you here, and "Oh Linux is banned" is a half-assed response from IT saying "We don't trust any old random systems, so we don't allow access."  As I said, it's network restrictions at play, and the Corporate IT policies.l